# Why does the version in a path in the Kubernetes API swagger file not match the version of all param/return values?

Tags: kubernetes, swagger, version

I'm doing some analysis on the swagger file that is supposed to generate the official Kubernetes Python client, and I put in a check just to see if the version named in a path ever differs from the version named in a parameter or return object, and it happens all over the place! Sometimes a v1 path has a param or return naming v1beta1 objects, and sometimes a beta path names v1 objects as params or returns. Just a couple of examples:

```
/api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}/eviction, post, body, path_ver=v1, param_ver=v1beta1

/apis/batch/v1beta1/, get, 200 code, path_ver=v1beta1, response_ver=v1
```

Is there some justification for this? In the eviction example above, there is no equivalent Eviction object in the v1 definition; shouldn't there be? This means that no single version is consistent and contained in and of itself. And in fact, in the case of the v1beta1 eviction object, it includes a reference to a v1 object, DeleteOptions. How can this be right? Is there an explanation that anyone can point me to?

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is the promotion of `v1beta1` resources to the `v1` API group, [as happened with Ingress](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/09/kubernetes-ingress-ga).

There's an internal mechanism that provides the conversion between resource versions when getting resources, as happening between `extensions/v1` and `networking.k8s.io/v1beta1`.

```
$ kubectl get ingresses.v1beta1.extensions
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
minimal-ingress   <none>   *                 80      5s

$ kubectl get ingresses.v1.networking.k8s.io
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
minimal-ingress   <none>   *                 80      27s
```

More details on the conversion is available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94761#issuecomment-691982480).

Comment: Thanks for the links; they are both illuminating and raise new issues. While providing reasons about what's going on (the soundness of which are debated in the Github issue), it leaves open questions on the search priority rule for each 'kind' in the absence of a version identifier or why v1 paths refer to v1beta1 versions of parameters or returns. It doesn't appear to be the case that when such mismatches exist, for example a v1beta1 path using a v1 parameters, there is also an equivalent v1 path. This seems to imply that such v1beta1 paths are part of v1. Is this understood to be the case?

Comment: Ah, it perhaps isn't a big deal. It appears that virtually every mismatch has to do with deleting something. The path is for pretty much any version you can think of, but the DeleteOptions is predominantly v1 (the value of the 'body' parameter). I'm still puzzled by this, but not as bothered as when I first started looking.